# QTextBrowser could not show all data at run time

Tags: c++, qt5, qtextbrowser

My problem is that QTextBrowser can not show all data that is appended to it.
I am using qt5.4 on windows.
My class like this:

```
class InfoTextBrowser : public QTextBrowser
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    InfoTextBrowser(QObject *parent);
    ~InfoTextBrowser();
public slots:
        void appendText(const QString& text) {

            try
            {

                this->append(text); 
            }
            catch(std::bad_alloc& e)
            {
                if(!memoryError)
                {
                    QMessageBox::warning(this,"My app", QStringLiteral("Out of Memory"),QMessageBox::Ok);
                    this->clear();
                    memoryError = true;
                }
            }

            QScrollBar* myBar = this->verticalScrollBar();
            if (myBar!=NULL)
                myBar->setValue(myBar->maximum());  
        };
private:
     void contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent *event);   
private:
    bool memoryError;
};
```

First I got bad_alloc exception and then I moved my application to 64bit then I do not get any exception. But When I run my program, QTextBrowser stops showing data after a while. It dies and it can not be cleared or refreshed.

I also tried QPlainTextEdit instead of this, but I could not be successful again. I want to show all data at run time or some part of it that could be shown. Because it stops just first paragraph when it dies. In addition, I do not want to show data by reading from a text file.

Is there anyone face with this situation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How much data are we talking about?

Comment: Around 100Mb. But it can be higher or lower...

Comment: Seems still a lot to me. What's the point of having so much text all displayed at once?

Comment: Sometimes, you can not decide the requirements :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I decided that there is no feasible solution for this, you can not hold this data at run time, It very depends on hardware. You do not have a guarantee to find the needed memory as a whole block.

So I used [QPlainTextEdit](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.4/qplaintextedit.html#maximumBlockCount-prop) and restricted to shown text as 100000 blocks by using `setMaximumBlockCount(100000)`function in the constructor. I appended text with `this->appendPlainText(text)`. Thus,output windows always shows last 100000 block of text. Rest of data can hold a text file or something like that. So user can look all of them from there.